# Dynamic Href not working using Javascript

Tags: javascript, cordova

```
function setLastLocation() {
        var lastLocation = window.location.pathname
        localStorage.setItem('lastLocation', lastLocation)
      }
```

Along with

```
function getLastLocation() {
        let lastLocation = localStorage.getItem('lastLocation')
        lastLocation = `../..${lastLocation}`
        return lastLocation
      }

<a href="javascript:getLastLocation()" class="close item item-1">
    <i class="fas fa-arrow-left fa-2x" style="color: white"></i>
</a>
```

Trying to make a back button for my cordova app to navigate to the previous page, but the href setup I have is not working the way I thought it would. There are two ways to get to the books of my app, by clicking on links from the search results or going to the books manually though the UI navigation. Depending upon which way the user gets to the books, I would like the href to redirect accordingly. The setLastLocation() is set on all the links leading to the content while the getLastLocation() is set on the back button of the actual content. When I type in the path for href literally (../../tracts.html), it works, but when I try to use the function in the href it doesn't work. Any suggestions? Here is a screen recording of the issue, [link](https://osaintilien55-gmail.tinytake.com/tt/NDYyNjM2Ml8xNDY2NTk0NQ).

Comment: did you try to debug it are those functions called is local storage set?

Comment: And when you use `window.localStorage` instead of `localStorage`?

Comment: @Xesenix here is a screen recording of the issue so you can see it clearly, [link](https://osaintilien55-gmail.tinytake.com/tt/NDYyNjM2Ml8xNDY2NTk0NQ) The code is actually working it's just that the Href is not doing what I expect it to do. I hope the problem is clear.

Comment: @Daantje Here is a screen recording of the issue so you can see it clearly, [link](https://osaintilien55-gmail.tinytake.com/tt/NDYyNjM2Ml8xNDY2NTk0NQ)   

When I swap localStorage for window.localStorage I get the same results unfortunately

Comment: “Returning” a value into `href="javascript:getLastLocation()"` won’t have the same effect, as clicking a link that has an actual URL set as `href`. You need to explicitly navigate to the target URL using code here, `location.href=…`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
href="javascript:getLastLocation()"
```

do

```
onclick="window.location = getLastLocation()"
```